# preg_replace_callback for this expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a preg_replace code in my php file:-

```
preg_replace('/<([^>]+)>/es', "'<'.sanitize('\\1',5).'>'",strip_tags($var, $allowable_tags))
```

I want to convert it into preg_replace_callback.

```
preg_replace_callback('/<([^>]+)>/s', function($m){return '<'.sanitize($m,5).'>';},strip_tags($var, $allowable_tags))
```

But it is not giving the same results. Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: do not parse/validate/sanitize html tags with regex

Comment: still it is not working. I just passed a string. But, no success so far.

Answer (score 0):

> But it is not giving the same results.

You use `'\\1'` in the `preg_replace` replacement string. The equivalent in the `preg_replace_callback` `function($m)` body were not `$m`, but `$m[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use clean interface of [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com)

```
pattern('<([^>]+)>', 's')->replace($input)->callback(function (Match $m) {
    return '<' . sanitize($m, 5) . '>';
});
```